# I can`t load multiple image in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I had my Images in src/postimages/(5 images) for each post one image,

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({
        id:"",
        blogImage:"",
        blogText:""
    });
                      
 <img src = {require('../../postimages/' + post.blogImage)} alt="Images" />
```

The Error is the following:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '../../postimages'

for one image I can access by importing the one image:

```
import blogImage from '../../postimages/img1.png';
```

How can I get 5 images respective with the different id`s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the single image name is, for example, `img1 (post.blogImage = 'img1')`

```
<img src={`{../../postimages/${post.blogImage}.png}`} alt="Images" />
```